# Как нажать на кнопку в браузере в C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-7

Есть кнопка на сайте `<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Войти" />`. На неё нужно нажать, как это сделать в коде c#? У неё нет ид, тегнейма и других атрибутов за которые можно схватиться.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, кстати. Только @eg01st, можно вас попросить использовать метку windowsphone7 вместо wp7? А то я этот вопрос еле нашел. З.Ы. А с Error: 80020101 справились? (да, я на SO я тоже бываю :)) Мне вот эту ошибку тоже выкидывает.

Comment: Error: 80020101 выпадал до того момента, пока на stackoverflow не дали строку wb1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();");, хотя, я по-моему писал эту же строку и получал ошибку. Магия вообщем)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wb1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();");
```

если кому-то интересно)

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, это  MVC? В таком случае пользуйтесь JavaScript'ом или, что еще проще, библиотекой JQuery. 
то есть выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
//далее идет клиентский JavaScript
$('.btn').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success: function() {
            alert('Ура, все работает!');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Кошмар! ничего не работает((');
        }
    });
}

//а теперь ваш C#
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
  // тут вы что-то делаете на сервере
}
```

Чтобы все это великолепие заработало, вам надо внести JavaScript-код в раздел скриптов, подключить библиотеку Jquery (можно и без нее, но тогда код по вызову ajax-запроса будет иным). Тут есть некоторые детали, но в целом - примерно так.

Comment: Нет, я наверное мало инфы дал. Обычный проект для windows phone 7, нужно нажать на сайте авторизации Вконтакте такую вот кнопку, чтобы зайти на страницу. Заполняю поля вот так 
    wb1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='{0}'", Login.Text));
    wb1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='{0}'", Pass.Password));
а вот как нажать на кнопку - не знаю(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("тут ID кнопки").InvokeMember("submit");
```

Comment: view-source:http://m.vk.com/login 
вот эта страничка, на ней есть кнопка 
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Войти" />
какой ид у этой кнопки?

Comment: Ну тут можно по другому:

    foreach(HTMLElement html in       webBrowser.Document.GetElementByTagName("input")){
     if(html.GetAttribute("value) == "Войти")
        html.InvokeMember("submit");
   }

Comment: мобильный браузер не содержит в себе Document(

Comment: Тогда извините, не знаю...

Comment: угу, я вот тоже долбаюсь) надеюсь что здесь подскажут)

Comment: Удачи вам в этом)