# Очистка cookies/программный вызов logout

Tags: c#, javascript, cookie, windows-phone-7, соцсети

Доброго времени суток всем.

При разработке приложения под Windows Phone 7 добавлял небольшую фичу, связанную с социальными сетями. Так как фича была откровенно маленькая решил обойтись без API. И написал довольно годный костяк, работая только через объект класса WebBrowser. Пример подобного подхода можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169594/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-c) Однако сейчас наткнулся на такую проблему, которую вообще не могу обойти. Итак:

**Суть** (тм):

Предположим мы работали с социальной сетью facebook. И в некоторый момент нам понадобилось сменить используемый аккаунт. Работаем мы через объект нэйтивного WP7-ского класса WebBroswer. (сам webBroswer на экране приложения естественно не виден, работа(скажем, обновление страницы пользователя) происходит автоматически). Для того чтобы сменить пользователя, нам естественно надо выйти. Вот тут и начинаются проблемы.

Если просто прекратить использование объекта webBroswer, это нам ничего не даст, ибо кукисы, и когда мы попытаемся зайти на **m.facebook.com/login** нас перенаправит на страницу этого пользователя.

***Вариант решения №1.***

Программно нажать на кнопку **logout**. Эта кнопка имеет вид

```
<a href="/logout.php?..." data-sigil="logout">Logout</a>
```

Кто знает, как на нее программно нажать? :)

***Вариант решения №2.***

Очистка cookies для этой страницы. Нашел вариант с использованием вебреквеста:

```
webRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri)
```

Он у меня всегда возвращает пустую коллекцию. Где я ошибаюсь, не знаю.

***Вариант решения №3.***

вписать в адресную строку webBroswer-у адрес, типа m.facebook.com/logout...

Как он должен выглядеть? Не знаю.

Кто поможет найти способ решения хотя бы одного из этих вариантов? (или предложит свой)

---

Надеюсь, объяснил не слишком сумбурно. Если что - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, кажется нашел способ для **решения №2**:

Для очистки cookies при перемещении на страницу делаем такую проверку для webBrowser:

```
private void webBrowser_SomePageLoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string source = webBrowser.Source.ToString();
            var cookies = webBrowser.GetCookies();

            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
            {
                if (cookie.Domain.Contains("m.facebook.com"))
                // очищаем для нужного домена
                {
                    cookie.Discard = true;
                    cookie.Expired = true;
                }
            }
```